# why wont multiple where clause work

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

I have 2 paramters ( **$memberparamter** and **$rest_id**), that i am getting from the user. But every time my server runs the statement, it does not find anything. I have double checked with my database, and it says the desired output, does exist. If i delete one of the where clause, it works great.

Have i done it the wrong way?

This is my sql statement:

```
  SELECT 
        eso.order_id as order_id,
        eso.member_id as member_id, 
        esoi.title as title, 
        dl.used_date as checked,
        dl.order_item_id as order_item_id 
        FROM exp_store_orders as eso
        inner join exp_store_order_items as esoi on (eso.order_id = esoi.order_id)
        inner join exp_deal_keys as dl on dl.order_item_id = esoi.order_item_id
        where eso.member_id = '$memberparamter' and esoi.entry_id = '$rest_id'
        and eso.order_paid > 0
        group BY eso.transaction_id 
        ORDER BY eso.transaction_id desc
```

Comment: Is there any sort of error message?

Comment: We would have to be able to see the data and the parameters that you are using.  Could you put up some sample data on SQLFiddle?

Comment: make sure your `$memberparamter` and `$rest_id` are getting the right values, than you can run sql to see if you get any rows.

Comment: is Member_Id and entry_ID numeric or string?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify *which* `where` clause fixes the problem.  If I were to speculate, I would guess that you misspelled `'$memberparamter'` and it really should be `'$memberparameter'` -- on the belief that you would spell "parameter" correctly in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Is it the GROUP BY that is causing the problem. Why do you have GROUP BY when you are not aggregating any of your SELECT columns?